# POSIX `pipe` both ways

Tags: unix, pipe, pty

I want to use (POSIX) `pipe` in a way to have it connected both ways. I.e. I can read and write at both ends.

Is that possible?

(I don't want to create two pipes with 4 file descriptors. I want to have only 2 file descriptors where I can read/write at both ends.)

Basically, it should be a fallback to `openpty` in case that fails.

Comment: What's wrong with using two pipes?

Comment: No, pipes are unidirectional. If you want bidirectional communication on a single fd, you could use a socket (possibly AF_UNIX) or -- as you suggest yourself -- a pty.

Comment: @Henning: As said, I cannot use `openpty` (because it should be a fallback for it). Could you post some sample code for the socket way? Also, why not putting that into an answer but rather a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes are strictly unidirectional.  But in a POSIX environment you may have access to the 'socketpair()' call which, when used with 'AF_UNIX" socket domain will give you a pair of bidirectional descriptors all connected and ready to go.  This is handy if you will fork and the descriptors get inherited.  If you are trying to connect two separate pre-existing processes, then you will need to create the sockets manually and use the sockets calls to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

I basically have this code now:

```
int fildes[2] = {-1,-1};
int ret = openpty(&fildes[0], &fildes[1], ttyname, &term, &win);
if(ret != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "openpty failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    ret = socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fildes);
    if(ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socketpair failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
}
```

Works somewhat but not quite right yet...